# "Shaze (社是)" Meaning, When it comes to person names?

Tags: meaning

Meaning of the word **"Shaze (社是)"** is **"Company Mission"** according to the Google Dictionary, even though there are lots of fake definitions around the internet.

But what is the meaning of **Shaze (社是)** when it comes to person names?

Examples : Shaze Tempain, Shaze Brown, Shaze Yukoha

Comment: Whether or not it is correct, a source like [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-Shaze), which purports to give the answer, should be included.

Comment: Are personal (given) names in scope for ELU?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Japanese, not English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, It's an English word. Origin is Japanese.

Comment: @NickSmith What is your basis for claiming that it’s an English word? I’ve certainly never heard it, and I can’t find it any dictionaries either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of meanings with this noun but when it comes to person names, these are the possible options

1. [Shaze Tempain](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-Shaze) is a Sri Lankan-American Rapper
2. [Silver Haze](https://www.google.com/search?q=silver%20haze&rlz=1C1CHWA_enLK647LK647&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJqfmXpOvYAhUBDKwKHcl6Df0Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662) = S.Haze = S+Haze
3. [Mission Planner](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=62284&j=%E7%A4%BE%E6%98%AF) (Origin : Japanese)
4. [Astronomical Sign which was using by ancient Sri Lankan people.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Astronomical_observatories_in_Sri_Lanka)

**And this is the meaning of the word “Shaze” when it comes as a person name:**

The Horoscope and Astrology meaning of the name Shaze: With a name number 5, your ruling planet is Mercury. You have a sharp mind, a quick thinking ability and are blessed with the great powers of speech. You have an extremely active life; are always on the road and possess great energy to accomplish even greater things. You are sometimes like a baby in an adult's body as you do not want to grow out of your teenage thoughts, mainly because your teenage experience is exemplary, keeps you happy and provides you with a strong motivating forward energy. You of course look younger than the actual age. You are great at reading and writing and are a great communicator.

Source : [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-name-Shaze)

Comment: Hello, Collin, and thank you for visiting ELU. I assume you found these by straightforward googling. That is the OP's job, and attributions and links should never be omitted.